# Line of best fit not accurate in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a line of best fit for a small scatter plot. Right now I am using

```
m,b = np.polyfit(xArray, yArray, 1)
xValues = np.linspace(-8,2,50)

plt.scatter(xList, yList)
plt.plot(xValues, m*xValues+b)
```

This keeps giving me a reasonable line of best fit, but what I am looking for is a more vertical line. What could I use as a substitue to polyfit when the data has a much higher down trend like this one?

Calculated best fit line:

[image: Calculated best fit line]

Comment: Slight nitpick: I would argue the calculated line _is_ the correct best fit. Look up how `polyfit()` works and the criteria it uses to determine the "goodness" of fit. If you want a vertical line that best fits the data, you could write a function that calculates the same quantity for vertical lines with your dataset and then maximizes this "goodness".

Comment: Typical least-squares approaches (like the one used by `polyfit`) minimize the sum of the squared differences of the vertical coordinate. What it sounds like you want is called the Total Least Squares solution, which effectively minimizes the sum of the distances to the line.

Comment: A statistician might be able to say this better than I can but linear regression is based on the errors in one observed variable (usually shown on the y-axis).  If you flip x and y and try to fit a line to the x-variable you will get a slightly different line.

Comment: The resulted m and b give the minimum least error. if you want a steeper value, this means you may want to give an initial slope m then looking for the value of b which gives the minimum least square error for this slope.

Comment: What do your data points represent, and what do you want the line to represent? The polyfit line is the minimum-mean-squared-error estimator of y given x, where x is an independent variable and y is a dependent one. So if that matches your situation this line is completely accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using orthogonal least squares instead of polyfit gives the desired answer. There is a built in package for this within scipy.

```
from scipy import odr

def linear_func(p, x):
   m, c = p
   return m*x + c

#Create a Model.:
linear = odr.Model(linear_func)

#Create a Data or RealData instance.:
mydata = odr.Data(xArray, yArray)

#or, when the actual covariances are known:
mydata = odr.RealData(x, y, sx=sx, sy=sy)

#Instantiate ODR with your data, model and initial parameter estimate.:
myodr = odr.ODR(mydata, linear, beta0=[1., 2.])

#Run the fit.:
myoutput = myodr.run()

#Examine output.:
myoutput.pprint()
```

[image: Example]

Instead of vertical distance to each point, this method uses perpendicular distance as shown above. This gives better fits for when your data has a strong down or up trend.

There are more detailed explanations on how to use this method here.

referece: [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html)